# Alternative to Tuxera NTFS and MacFUSE?

Tags: usb, macbook-pro, ntfs, filesystem

Im trying to mount files to an NTFS format drive, I read on the internet that either Tuxera NTFS or MacFuse work for such things. However TuxeraNTFS filled my USB drive with space that should be free after file deletion, and I had to use windows to access the drive and delete the hidden folders created by Tuxera. MacFuse never installed correctly and states that "MacFuse does not appear to be installed"..

Is there any other reliable program that 100% works with NTFS drives ?

Platform : rMBP Mountain Lion OSX 10.8

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several programs that provide NTFS support. However, I would hesitate to claim that any of these programs can provide 100% compatibility and support.

Here's a subset of the NTFS list in [Richard Austin's Blog Champion's](http://blogchampion.com/2012/04/06/file-system-choices-in-mac-os-x/) discussion of OS X file system choices:

- [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) - I've used this program with no issues in Lion and Mountain Lion
- [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) - site claims to support Mountain Lion, personally haven't used
- [OSX Fuse](http://osxfuse.github.com/) - a freeware successor, don't know if it works with Mountain Lion, personally haven't used

I don't have a retina MBP to test with, but any of these should offer you a good starting point. Since you've already tried Tuxera, Paragon appears to be your best bet, while OSX Fuse would be a good option to try out.

Answer (score 3):

[FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com/) works just fine. I am currently using this in Mountain Lion.

I tried this order and it worked fine.

1. Install [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com/)
2. Install [NTFS-3G](http://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/NTFS-3G%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/2010.10.2/ntfs-3g-2010.10.2-macosx.dmg/download)

   REBOOT
3. Install [fuse_wait](https://github.com/downloads/bfleischer/fuse_wait/fuse_wait.pkg)

   REBOOT

(source http://i.vishalagarwal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For 10.7 I used NTFS 3G with MacFUSE, everything was fine. Now with 10.8 I use Seagate free NTFS driver (the same as comercial Paragon NTFS for Mac), also works well. Great when purchasing an external HDD you get free driver for it!:)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is the arguably most expensive and least convenient, but also the most reliable and can either be one-time or for a permanent arrangement.

Share the drive from a Windows machine capable of handling NTFS.  Read/write files using the SMB client built into OS X and not worry about native filesystem support compatibility issues.