# Unlock read-only USB key

Tags: snow-leopard, usb, permission, mount, unlock

A free 8GB USB key given to me shows up in Snow Leopard as read-only.

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on /Volumes/USB DISK (ntfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

How can I mount it read-write? According to the provider of the USB key:

*"The USB needs to be unlocked. Right click USB-properties-security-select everyone-edit-permissions for everyone-Allow full control"*

But I think these must be instructions for a different OS.

I'd be fine with reformatting it - there's nothing valuable on it.

Attempting to force the issue with `mount` doesn't seem to work:

```
$ sudo mount -w -t ntfs /dev/disk1 "/tmp/USB"
$ touch /tmp/USB/foo
-bash: foo: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 5):

It's read-only because it's formatted with NTFS (the Windows filesystem), which OS X can only read without the help of third party software. If reformatting isn't a problem, then that's likely the easiest way to go. If you need to transfer between OS X and Windows with the stick, use the FAT filesystem. If you're just using it with Macs, the defaults will work fine.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58721/alternative-to-tuxera-ntfs-and-macfuse lists several products that provide read/write access to NTFS filesystems. I've been using Tuxera since Snow Leopard and had no issues so far.

Comment: Thanks. Discovered today that formatting it with "the defaults" indeed wasn't readable by Windows.